# Add a chracter to data in MySQL column temporarily for a select query

Tags: php, mysql, select

is there anyway to add a character to every row in the column in a select query?

For example something like:

```
"SELECT * FROM table where data+' ' LIKE '%value %'"
```

Notice the `+' '`, which is what I am trying to add, basically I want it to add a space to the end of the data value so when it searches using `LIKE` it will recognize the space at the end.

Comment: Why not `WHERE data LIKE '%value%'` (notice no space after `value`)?

Comment: @deceze He wants to find a word **ending** with `value`

Comment: but OP does not seems to have a data of word+space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is called `concat`

```
where concat(data, ' ') like '%value %';       <-- adding space at back

where concat(' ', data) like '%value %';       <-- adding space in-front

where concat(' ', data, ' ') like '%value %';  <-- adding space in-front, back
```

details : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

alternatively, you can do this instead

```
where data like concat('%', rtrim(value), '%');
```

this is to [`rtrim`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_rtrim) the space of value to search

note: with space or without space might affect the match results

Comment: Thanks, but how can I add a space to the front of as well?